# Google Map Marker change when reclick again - Fidde attached

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, marker

Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tp2f74sz/

Basically what I want to achieve is when I click it changes to green, but **when I re-click I want to change it back to black again.** Now It changes when I click the  close icon

Please help

Thank

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        
       id: this.id,
        content:this.html,
     pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30),
        position:this.getPosition({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(500,0)})
        
        
      });
          
    

      var markerrr = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  icon: 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png'
});
      
      
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
       markers[this.id].setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png');
        
      });
      
      this.setVisible(true);

      infowindow.open(map);
      this.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `click` listener, check which icon is being displayed, then switch it to the other one using `.setIcon()`: http://jsfiddle.net/7zqde3kn/

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
  if (this.icon.includes('black')) {
    this.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
  } else {
    this.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png');
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137650/select-marker-with-external-input-form

Comment: can you help in this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137650/select-marker-with-external-input-form

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you :)